# MySql Workbench AI flag ( auto increment )

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got two MySQL servers, one on Linux and one on Windows. When I try to ALTER one table, the one that is on Linux got a marker on AI check box; but when I ALTER the table that is on Windows the property is on, but is not marked on the check box.

Could you explain why is this happening?

I will appreciate you're help, since nobody has ever explain this in previous questions.

Thanks.